# Extract and Expand A Range of Serial Number

Tags: excel, vba

I have input of example ABC100-10. Meaning, it is a range of:

```
ColA  |
ABC100|
ABC101|
...   |
ABC110|
```

How can I copy paste "ACB100-10" into a cell, and then have Excel to expand it out to ABC100,ABC101,...,ABC110 in a column ? I am aware of dragging down to expand.. but I do not want this method :)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need VBA for this task? I was able to write `ABC100` into cell `A1` then drag the entry down to cell `A11`, which auto-populated the cells per your request

Comment: Wagner, I would like to copy "ACB100-10" and then have Excel to expand and populate it down the column. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you run this macro the column will be populated from the ActiveCell on down:

```
Sub KolumnKreator()
    Dim s As String, K As Long, N As Long, T As String
    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter input", Type:=2)
    If InStr(1, s, "-") = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ary = Split(s, "-")
    K = CLng(ary(1))
    N = NumPart(ary(0))
    T = TexPart(ary(0))
    For i = 0 To K
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = T & N + i
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function NumPart(Inn) As Long
    temp = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Inn)
        ch = Mid(Inn, i, 1)
        If ch Like "[0-9]" Then temp = temp & ch
    Next i
    NumPart = CLng(temp)
End Function

Public Function TexPart(Inn) As String
temp = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Inn)
        ch = Mid(Inn, i, 1)
        If Not ch Like "[0-9]" Then temp = temp & ch
    Next i
    TexPart = temp
End Function
```